# Fastest way to determine if a single row exists in a another joined table, equivalent of the ANY linq function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to return a bit field for a join onto another table but where if a single record exists it returns '1' and if none exist it returned '0'. I can't afford to slow down the operation so it needs to be the most efficient solution possible. I am trying to achieve this on the HasRecord line in the select statement - this currently doesn't work.

```
SELECT 
    AVG(CS.HourMinutes00) AS HourMinutes00,
    AVG(CS.HourMinutes01) AS HourMinutes01,
    AVG(CS.HourMinutes02) AS HourMinutes02,
    AVG(CS.HourMinutes03) AS HourMinutes03,
    AVG(CS.HourMinutes04) AS HourMinutes04,
    AVG(CS.HourMinutes05) AS HourMinutes05,
    AVG(CS.HourMinutes06) AS HourMinutes06,
    AVG(CS.HourMinutes07) AS HourMinutes07,
    AVG(CS.HourMinutes08) AS HourMinutes08,
    AVG(CS.HourMinutes09) AS HourMinutes09,
    AVG(CS.HourMinutes10) AS HourMinutes10,
    AVG(CS.HourMinutes11) AS HourMinutes11,
    AVG(CS.HourMinutes12) AS HourMinutes12,
    AVG(CS.HourMinutes13) AS HourMinutes13,
    AVG(CS.HourMinutes14) AS HourMinutes14,
    AVG(CS.HourMinutes15) AS HourMinutes15,
    AVG(CS.HourMinutes16) AS HourMinutes16,
    AVG(CS.HourMinutes17) AS HourMinutes17,
    AVG(CS.HourMinutes18) AS HourMinutes18,
    AVG(CS.HourMinutes19) AS HourMinutes19,
    AVG(CS.HourMinutes20) AS HourMinutes20,
    AVG(CS.HourMinutes21) AS HourMinutes21,
    AVG(CS.HourMinutes22) AS HourMinutes22,
    AVG(CS.HourMinutes23) AS HourMinutes23,
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM LocationHistory LH JOIN MachineActivity MA ON LH.MachineActivityId = MA.Id JOIN Machine M ON MA.MachineId = M.Id WHERE CS.ActivityDate = MA.ActivityDate AND CS.MachineId = M.Id) THEN CAST (1 AS BIT) ELSE CAST (0 AS BIT) END AS HasRecord
FROM 
    CustomerSummary
WHERE
    ActivityDate >= '2021-02-15'
AND
    ActivityDate <= '2021-02-21'
AND 
    CS.MachineNumber = '1'
AND
    CS.SiteId = '1'
GO
```

Comment: Please explain what  "doesn't work" means.

Comment: The *real* problem looks like you have a massively denormalised table. Also, do you *really* need that `NOLOCK`? You do understand what it does, right?

Comment: Removed nolock for clarity as was just in testing. Correct as to denormalised but have to work with what's been given.

Comment: "Doesn't work" - throws an error which is understandable as it's not the correct solution simply there to show the current approach.

Comment: You don't need to "help" the query optimizer. It knows it can return a true result as soon as a single row is found in an `EXISTS` test.

Comment: The fastest method is to supply good indexing to the compiler. You want an index on `LH.MachineActivityId` and `MA.ActivityDate, MA.MachineId` (or perhaps the other way round, put most selective column first)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subqueries with aggregation are usually tricky.  You can fix the syntax issue by moving the logic to the `FROM` clause using `APPLY`:

```
SELECT . . .,
       v.HasRecord
FROM  CustomerSummary CS CROSS APPLY
      (VALUES (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                 FROM LocationHistory LH JOIN 
                                      MachineActivity MA
                                      ON LH.MachineActivityId = MA.Id JOIN
                                      Machine M
                                      ON MA.MachineId = M.Id
                                 WHERE CS.ActivityDate = MA.ActivityDate AND
                                       CS.MachineId = M.Id
                               )
                    THEN CAST (1 AS BIT)
                    ELSE CAST (0 AS BIT)
               END)
      ) v(HasRecord)
WHERE . . .
GROUP BY v.HasRecord;
```

This should be performant.

Notes:

- Do not use `NOLOCK` unless you really know what you are doing.  Most users do not want inconsistent data used for their results.
- `SELECT TOP` is not needed with `EXISTS`.

Comment: Thanks Gordan, the solution works but adds an extra 6 seconds to the query execution time which will likely be the huge dataset it is joining on... Might need to rethink this if I can't find a quicker solution.

Comment: An index on `CustomerSummary(MachineNumber, ActivityDate)` might help.